# split function in java script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change the extinsion of .doc to .txt.
 alert(myvar) show empty alert.

```
enter code here
 <form>
 <input type="file" id="f1">
<button onclick="myFunction(f1.value)">Try it</button>
 </form>
  <script>
    function myFunction(a) {
      var mystr = a;
      var myarr = mystr.split(".doc");
      var ex= ".txt";
      var myvar = myarr + ex;
      alert(myvar);
       }
</script>
```

Comment: var myvar = myarr[0] + ex; .. myArr is an array dude =)

Comment: and var mystr = a; use var mystr = "a"; it's a string

Comment: oh course it shows and empty array, f1.value dosnt mean anything, so you are passing undefined to the myFunction

Comment: I want to do this by geting the textbox id

Comment: I tried to fetch this using document.getElementById(f1) I dont know why this is not working

Comment: don not use split check my solution at below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> please try the given below code.also follow the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/mrdzmd0o/)

```
In html:
<input type="file" id="f1">
<input type="button" value="myfun" onclick="myFunction(f1.value)">

In js:

window.myFunction = function(a) {
 var file = a;
 file = file.split(".");
 file = file[0]+".txt"; 
 alert(file);
```

}

Comment: I want to remove c:/fekepath/ from file alert.Is It possible

Comment: yea!! it is possible just follow this link:http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/mrdzmd0o/1/

Comment: @PratikPatel : Then also it should work perfectly :). check link below: http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/tb5s4uza/

Comment: @Priyank "test" is dropped from filename in ue demo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67368/discussion-between-priyank-and-pratik-patel).

Answer (score 3):

use str.replace function

```
mystr.replace(".doc", ".txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

you have array whwn used split function . so

```
<script>
    function myFunction(a) {
      var mystr = a;
      var myarr = mystr.split(".doc");
      var ex= ".txt";
      var myvar = myarr[0] + ex;
      alert(myvar);
       }
</script>
```

Comment: how can I do this by geting Id of this text box without passing parameter a in function

Comment: you can implement  $("#textboxID").val() instead of a . without passing parameter in function .

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
 <input type="file" id="f1">
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test(f1.value)">


function test(a){
    var file = a;
file = file.split(".");
file = file[0]+".html"; //any extension you want
 alert(file);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeExt(s){
    if(s.substring(s.length - 3,s.length) == "doc"){
        var s = s.substring(0,s.length - 3);
        s += "txt";
        return s;
    }
    else{
        return 'bad ext';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    function myFunction(a) {
      var mystr = a;
      var myarr = mystr.split(".doc")[0];
      var ex= ".txt";
      var myvar = myarr + ex;
      alert(myvar);
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> please try the given below code.also follow the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrdzmd0o/4/)

```
In html:
<input type="file" id="f1">
<input type="button" value="myfun" onclick="myFunction(f1.value)">

In js:

window.myFunction = function(fileName) {
    var newFileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    newFileName = newFileName+".txt"; 
     alert(newFileName);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you choose spilit function when jquery provide us replace string and its variable too.
here is example

```
  var str = "Prabhash Rawat";
  var res = str.replace("Rawat", "Huda");
```

after run this example the output of this script will be

```
Prabhash Huda
```